# Adding more item inside filterable portfolio in wordpress theme

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery

In my wordpress theme I have created custom post type page for "portfolio" and implemented Isotop-jquery filtering for categories items (images or video). This works as usual. Now I want to implement "load more" button to load  more items instantly without page load.I searched out lot for this on Google, but not getting useful guideline to implement it for portfolio items. Is any one can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You need AJAX. On "load more" action send a ajax request which would return the post of that category. You can refer to this [Wordpress+ajax](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX)